How to get the body from the POST request correctly in the Django Rest Framework
All I want is to get the body from my request, but I don't understand how to do it, I tried request.data but it returns a string, after I tried using json.loads(request.data), but it just refused to work. I just want to parse the nested json, why is it so difficult in Django.
My code
class TestCheckView(views.APIView):
    
    def post(self, request, pk):
        result = Result()
        test_id = request.data.get("id")
        data = dict(request.data)
        
        for question in data["questions"]:
            print(type(question))
            for answer in question["answers"]:
                result.total += 1
                if Answer.objects.get(id=answer["id"],question_id=question["id"]):
                    result.score += 1
        result.test = Test.objects.get(id=test_id)
        result.save()
                    

what i want get
"id":1,
"title":"Тест по теме тестов",
"questions":[
   {
      "id":1,
      "title":"Вопрос 1",
      "answers":[
         {
            "id":1,
            "title":"Ответ 1",
            "is_right":true
         },
         {
            "id":2,
            "title":"Ответ 2"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "id":2,
      "title":"Вопрос 2",
      "answers":[
         {
            "id":3,
            "title":"Ответ 1",
            "is_right":true
         }
      ]
   }
]
}


Did you set the type to application/json in the HTML Form ? See https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/ and https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#data EDIT : For an HTML form it seems request.data is  a QueryDict

Exelent, ths you very much

Often you use serializers exactly to make it a lot more easy to parse nested structures.
